# Google maps api and custom markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the google maps api and want to create some custom markers, they are all the same apart from the color, I don't want to repeat code like so

```
 // Add a custom marker
var marker1 = {
    path: 'M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z',
    fillColor: '#ff61b4',
    fillOpacity: 0.95,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: '#fff',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 24)
};

var marker2 = {
    path: 'M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z',
    fillColor: '#05950a',
    fillOpacity: 0.95,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: '#fff',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 24)
};
```

When i want to use the marker

```
 // Markers
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    icon: marker, // can i override the fillColor here ?
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(51.489401, -3.203586),
    title: 'title'
});
```

I would like to be able to declare one marker and then override the fillColor, how could i go about this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a function to generate the icon (i.e. a `createIcon` function), which takes the color as an argument and returns the icon anonymous object:

```
function createIcon(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 0.95,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: '#fff',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 24)
  };
}
```

Then use that when you create the markers:

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 37.448,
      lng: -122.143
    },
    icon: createIcon('#ff61b4')
  });
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ocnymvL3/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function createIcon(color) {
  return {
    path: 'M12 2C8.13 2 5 5.13 5 9c0 5.25 7 13 7 13s7-7.75 7-13c0-3.87-3.13-7-7-7zm0 9.5c-1.38 0-2.5-1.12-2.5-2.5s1.12-2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.12 2.5 2.5-1.12 2.5-2.5 2.5z',
    fillColor: color,
    fillOpacity: 0.95,
    scale: 2,
    strokeColor: '#fff',
    strokeWeight: 3,
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(12, 24)
  };
}

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
    icon: createIcon('blue')
  });
  var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 37.448,
      lng: -122.143
    },
    icon: createIcon('#ff61b4')
  })
  var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: {
      lat: 37.44,
      lng: -122.148
    },
    icon: createIcon('#05950a')
  });

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, makes a lot of sense :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use  setOptions, eg: for changing only the icon

```
marker.setOptions({
     icon = "http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png"
});
```

or clickable

```
marker.setOptions({clickable:false});
```

so you can  do the same for all the marker  options